# How can I make magnetize alignment

Tags: java, android, button, drag-and-drop, alignment

[My Game Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVH9D.jpg) I code a block puzzle game, I have created a board with buttons, I will create some block. 
Question, When user drag and drop this block in somewhere of the board, the block have to align to exact cells. I don't use and other framework and game engine.